# Trying to get property 'employee' of non-object (View: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/al-halal/resources/views/leave/allLeave.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel

have been trying to get the output of these code from my vew but its giving me issues, Please i woild really be bappy to get help.

In my controller

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use App\leaveType;
use App\allLeave;
use App\leaveDepartment;

class LeavesController extends Controller
{
    public function getAllLeave()
    {
        $data = App\allLeave::find(1)->full_name;
        return view('leave/allLeave',["data"=>$data]);
    }
}
```

in my employee model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

/**
 * Class Personnel
 * @package App
 */
class Employee extends Audit
{
    public function leave()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\allLeave');
    }
}
```

In allLeaveModel

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class allLeave extends Model
{
    public function empolyee()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Employee');
    }
}
```

in the blade

```
{{$data->employee->full_name}}
```

Comment: I only see you trying to use `employees` property not `employee` ... and I assume your relationship `function empolyee` is a typo?

Comment: `$data` is a string not an object ... you are passing a string from the controller `$data = App\allLeave::find(1)->full_name` is a string

Comment: @lagbox sorry for the mistake have corrected it now. its employee not employees and as for the function its not a typo its the function in the model that seves as relationship with the other table

Comment: why is it named `empolyee` ? shouldn't it be `employee` .. or because it is a HasMany `employees`?

Comment: @lagbox i just named it like that to make it easy for me to remeber thats the function i used for thr relationship

Comment: then if `$data` wasn't a string, you would need to access that relationship via the dynamic property `empolyee` not `employee`, `$data->empolyee->full_name` ... what data do you actually want to be sent to the view?

Comment: @lagbox its the full_name i want to send to the view from employee table, how do i access a relationship with a dynamic property?

Comment: @NICANDIAS I think Problem in a relationship. OP did not add foreign key right way

Comment: allLeave can have many employees, which employee's full name do you want? you have to think through this more ... and assuming the relationship is setup correctly ... and in the example code `$data` is probably `null` not a string, my bad assumption previously

Comment: @amit please can we chat on anyother plat form so as to make me able to show you the picture of the two tables and enable me explain better if needed

Comment: @lagbox ita a table that should display all the employers that ever requested for leave, so the table contains the full and and some other details but the bio data is not on the same table as the the leave details. so thats why am trying to merge both tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i have to do the same i will do it simply like

```
 <?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use App\leaveType;
use App\allLeave;
use App\leaveDepartment;

class LeavesController extends Controller
{
    public function getAllLeave()
    {
           /* No need to use App\allLeave because you already have that used in 
              top of the project */
           $data=allLeave::findorFail(1);
           return view('leave.allLeave')->with('data', $data);
    }
}
```

in front end just use

```
{{$data->first_name}} //same column as in database table
```

Note: Make sure are using laravel eloquent model relationships

Comment: please use dd($data) before returning values to view so that you know that this record exists or not!

Answer (score 4):

You already assign full name to data in controller. You only need `{{ $data }}` in blade

Comment: `full_name` is actually on a different table, otherwise yes, the OP's code is their attempt

Comment: there is hasMany employees. you must foreach that. you find `allLeave` (remove full name) and then you call employees and that is collections. you must go through all data and call full name attribute

Answer (score 0):

In your controller should be like this:

```
$data = App\allLeave::find(1)->empolyee();
```

And your blade:

```
{{$data->full_name}}
```